# How to initialize an array of doubles in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer

I realized that in c++ I cannot initialize an array of `double` with `memset`. For an integer array I can easily initialize the array using:

```
int* a = new int[n];
memset(a, n*n, n*sizeof(int));
```

But how can I initialize an array of doubles in c++?

```
long double* d = new long double[n];
memset(d, n*n, n*sizeof(long double)); // does not work
```

Comment: Try [`std::fill`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8848575/)

Comment: Why not use universal initialization syntax? `auto x = new T[N]{};` still, that's only good if you want to zero-initialize...

Comment: @Nemo fill is used for `std::arrray`, is it used for my c style arrays?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Because he's trying to initialize to a non-zero value.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That does not allow you to specify the value to initialize the elements with.

Comment: `std::fill` will work on any iterable container. So `std::fill(d, d+n, n*n)` should do what you want

Comment: @Deduplicator The syntax is not limited to default-initialization.  You can also do `new double[n]{42}`.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Sure, but only for those elements you designate at compile-time.

Comment: @Nemo, I guess c++11 should be enabled, I am trying it ;)

Comment: `std::fill` has been around since C++98 with the same semantics. And most compilers optimize it pretty well.

Comment: @Nemo using g++ must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11. But it worked. Cheers

Comment: @Deduplicator I have again learned something. ;-)

Comment: @Nemo, is there any other option? because it seems that I don't have any of c++11 and gnu++11 available on my test machine (and obviously I can't install them)

Comment: @emab: Again, `std::fill` has been in standard C++ since the original standard was ratified in 1998. If you seem to need C++11, you are doing something wrong... Did you remember to `#include <algorithm>`, for instance? If you can post a short test program in a different question that does not work, someone will surely help you fix it.

Answer (score -2):

```
memset(a, n*n, n*sizeof(int));
```

This is probably not doing what you expect. The doc says that the value param is converted to an unsigned char.    Each byte will be set to that value.  When you look at the 4 or 8 bytes that comprise an int, you'll get junk.  The only useful value I've seen passed in is 0.  That will work to init a double as well

The only way to initialize an array of numerics to a known value, like 42, is to write a loop

Comment: "That will work to init a double as well" - Not in portable code. The spec permits `0.0` to be represented in ways other than all-zero.

Comment: You don't need to write a loop. Use `std::fill`

Comment: Every modern CPU architecture I'm aware of uses IEEE floating point, for which all bytes zero is the representation of 0.0.  I'm familiar with the old VAX format, but it also used all bytes zero to represent 0.0.  While the spec permits other architectures, it's not something I worry about.