# efficient way to initialize a vector with zero after constructor

Tags: c++

what is the most efficient way to initialize a vector? I don't want to initialize it in the constructor.

```
struct st{
        std::vector<int> var_dynamic;
        int i;
};
int main(){
for ( int k=1 ; k<10 ; k++)
{
        struct st st1;
        st1.i=1;
        int i = 999; // some integer value
        st1.var_dynamic.reserve(100000000); // make room for 10 elements
        std::vector<int> vec(1000,0);
        for (int n=1; n<1000000;n++)
        {
                st1.var_dynamic.push_back(1);
        }
} 
}
```

I think this method couldn't be efficient.

Comment: Please study a (vector) documentation, before asking those questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848575/fastest-way-to-reset-every-value-of-stdvectorint-to-0

Comment: Just for completeness ( I can't post another answer), 
I mention that you can use **memset** even on `std::vector<T>` as soon as T is a Plain old Data (POD) (native C type or simple structs built from them)

`memset(&var[0], 0, sizeof(var[0]) * var.size())`

Notice that this method should fail on bool datatype.

Another approach could be to use the **fill** function available in the **algorithm** header as following:
`std::fill(var.begin(),var.end(),0)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think this method couldn't be efficient.

Well, you can just use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
 std::vector<int> var(100000000,0);
```

or the [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function

```
 var.resize(100000000,0);
```

---

I'd suspect these are implemented as efficient as can be, while doing yourself using `push_back()` may have some unwanted side effects.

Comment: thanks, resize worked for me, because I didn't want to initialize it in constructor

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<int> vec(100000000,0); // 100000000 integers with the value 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
 std::vector<int> var(100000000, 0);
```