# C++ - std::vector initialisation in constructor

Tags: c++, oop, vector, constructor, initialization

In my learning process about C++, I am having hard time understanding the best practice for initializing a vector in this particular setting:

```
struct Data {
    vector<int> vec;

    Data(const int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) vec.push_back(0);
    }
};
```

so that in the main function I just declare `Data mydata(10);` and `mydata` will have an attribute vector `mydata.vec` of `k=10` elements.

However, I really find unefficient that one has to setup a for loop and fill `mydata.vec` element by element, so looking online I found other methods that honestly I did not understand. Anyway, I tried to replace that given constructor with

```
Data(const int k) {
    vec.resize(k);
}
```

and

```
Data(const int k) : vec(k,0) {}
```

with either error messages about modified objects already deleted or segmentation faults happening during runtime. Would you please explain the most C++'ish or most efficient way to initialise a vector in such framework? Consider that for some reason I have little to no understanding about what an initialization list is.

EDIT:
Here I propose a minimal example directly taken from my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Data {
    vector<unsigned int> mydata, count;

    Data(const unsigned int k) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * k; i++) {
            mydata.push_back(i + 1);
            //count.push_back(0);  // HERE 1
        }
        count.resize(k); // HERE 2
    }

    void update_stats(const unsigned int p) { count[mydata[0] - 1] += 1; }
};

void twist(Data& stuff, const unsigned int m) {
    unsigned int temp;
    for (unsigned int i = m; i < 2 * m; i++) {
        temp = stuff.mydata[i];
        stuff.mydata.erase(stuff.mydata.begin() + i);
        stuff.mydata.insert(stuff.mydata.begin() + (i - m) * 2, temp);
    }
    stuff.update_stats(m);
}

int main() {
    unsigned int p, k = 200;
    Data stuff(k);

    for (p = 1; p <= k; p++) twist(stuff, p);
    for (p = k; p >= 1; p--) twist(stuff, p);

    cout << stuff.count[stuff.mydata[0] - 1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am sorry to not to do better in reducing further. This code produces a segmentation fault. However, commenting the `HERE 2` line and using `HERE 1` apparently saves the situation. I don't get why.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](https://ideone.com/2HWDkg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [efficient way to initialize a vector with zero after constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683151/efficient-way-to-initialize-a-vector-with-zero-after-constructor)

Comment: @rezaebrh, no it is not helping me because I would like to initialise the vectors right in the constructor rather than after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `for` loop

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * k; i++)
    count.push_back(0);
```

the `count` vector will contain `2k` zeros. But after `count.resize(k)` it will contain only `k` zeros.

---

Fixed constructor might look like this:

```
Data(const unsigned int k) : mydata(2 * k), count(2 * k, 0) {
    std::iota(mydata.begin(), mydata.end(), 1u);
}
```

To assign sequentially increasing sequence to `mydata`, you can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) algorithm. `, 0` can be dropped without changing the behaviour, but you might want to be explicit about the initial value.

Semantics of these two [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is very simple:

> `explicit vector(size_type count);`
>
> Constructs the container with `count` default-inserted instances of `T`. No copies are made.
>
> `vector(size_type count, const T& value);`
>
> Constructs the container with `count` copies of elements with value `value`.

For `T = unsigned int`, the "default-inserted instance" is just `0u`.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is basically what I was looking for. Thank you so much.